# Hibernate JPA - PESSIMISTIC.WRITE not working

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, locking

I'm using the Hibernate implementation of JPA 2.0 to create a counter in a table row.  I'm using MySQL 5.5 with the InnoDB engine.   I am trying to lock the counter row so that no processes outside the JVM can view that counter until my code has incremented it.   My code looks like this:

```
  //inside a Transaction....

  //key is an enum
  final PropertyKey key = PropertyKey.DEPLOY_COUNTER;
  final Query query =
     entityManager.createQuery("FROM Property s where propertyKey = :key").setParameter("key", key);
  query.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
  LOG.debug("Blocking (maybe) while waiting to update deploy counter");
  final Property counterAsProperty = (Property) query.getSingleResult();

  try
  {
     Thread.sleep(15000);
     //while sleeping I use MySQL cli to check value of property in database
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

  //in java, increment counter by one and then save in db
  //...
```

I use Thread.sleep() to pause the code in the middle of the transaction.  While the thread is sleeping, I use the MySQL CLI client to log into the database and check the value of the property. That session looks something like this:

```
user@mypc [user]> begin work;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

user@mypc [user]> select * from property where property_key = 'DEPLOY_COUNTER';
+----+---------+-----------+--------------------+----------------+
| id | version | encrypted | property_key       | property_value |
+----+---------+-----------+--------------------+----------------+
| 10 |       0 |         0 | DEPLOY_COUNTER     | 66             |   
+----+---------+-----------+--------------------+----------------+
```

Notice how the query returns immediately(0.00 sec) when I expected it to block until the thread had quit sleeping and the transaction completed.   My understanding of LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE is that it should put the retrieved row in an exclusive lock, unavailable for reading or writing by another transaction.

NOTE:  updates to this row do block while the thread is sleeping.

Why can another DB connection view the data when the other transaction is running if I've set PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock mode?

Answer (score 1):

The default InnoDB isolation level is REPEATABLE READ, which allows transactions without the exclusive lock to read (but not update) the locked record.  This allowed other transactions to do non-dirty reads on the record.  SERIALIZABLE appears to prevent any reads on a locked record.  You can set the isolation level when setting up the hibernate connection properties with [hibernate.connection.isolation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html), although this would affect all connections, not a cost I was willing to pay.   This SO post indicates a way to do it per connection, but the approach requires deprecated methods: [JPA and MySQL transaction isolation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924147/jpa-and-mysql-transaction-isolation-level)

I wound up using one of the

```
UPDATE counter SET value = LAST_INSERT_ID(value + 1);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

approaches cited here: http://tedyoung.me/2011/04/14/jpa-counters-and-sequences/, which didn't require any locking.

Answer (score 0):

For select queries this doesn't works

It will work if you query for 'select for update'
then your query will wait till the time your application doesn't releases the lock

```
select * from property where property_key = 'DEPLOY_COUNTER' for update;
```

Above query will wait until the lock is released.